# IQ data for analog FM modulation

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation, quadrature

I am trying to understand how I can produce analog FM modulation using IQ data.

So far, I know to generate the FM modulation with an IQ modulator (like the LTC5599.) I have to apply IQ data in quadrature mode like this-
I=cos(phase), Q=sin(phase).

I have generated the IQ data using a frequency generator using stereo mode, so they are synchronized with each other with phase shift of 90.

[image]

For LO (LTC5599) I have generated a frequency of 492.8 MHz with the default settings of the LTC5599.

When I observe the RF output with a spectrum analyzer, I see something other than FM modulation.

[image]

I think I am missing something.  Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you modulate the frequency?

Comment: The IQ data is directly connected to the LTC559 IQ input. Although, i used single ended where in LTC5599 input is differential. The modulation is done inside of the LTC5599.

Comment: yes, did you modulate the frequency of the I/Q? It looks like your I/Q is a 1kHz sine wave; if you then modulate this onto a 492.8MHz carrier you get a 492.801MHz or 492.799MHz sine wave (depending which way around it is). I guess you have some distortion going on which causes these other frequency spikes

Comment: I think, i misunderstand you. The Local Oscillator is applied already (492.8 MHz) in the LTC5599, So, the modulation is happening inside of the chip. Yes, i agree with you like you said, "492.8MHz carrier you get a 492.801MHz or 492.799MHz sine wave". However, i thought i would see a fm modulation in time domain (i did check that by lower the frequency of LO(100MHz) in order to see it with 2.5GHz scope). But, it was not FM, it is more to AM.

Comment: If you do not frequency-modulate the I/Q signal in the time domain then you will not get a frequency-modulated output signal in the time domain. You are putting in one frequency and you are getting out one frequency (plus some harmonics caused by distortion that you'll probably have to fix because they are quite large). Were you expecting the mixer to hallucinate some audio signal out of nowhere?

Comment: Looks like you have mixed AM and FM. Are your I and Q channels of equal gain? Check by modulating with I alone, then with Q alone, and compare the amplitudes for equality.

Comment: With all due respect, maybe i am wrong. The mixer LTC5599 modulate my IQ data in real time. In my case, 1kHz is the audio data i want to modulate. So i generate the IQ data of 1KHz with phase shift, then ltc5599 modulate the audio with local oscillator. Then they add the both channel to the output of the mixer. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @Neil_UK , i check the iq data separately, they are both have same gain.

Comment: Do you know how to take your audio signal and convert it into a phase signal? It looks like you do know how to convert the phrase signal into I and Q signals (take the cosine and sine, as you mentioned at the beginning).

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. From real audio signal to convert in IQ data, we can take the real audio as I data and do the hilbert transform to convert into the Q data. In my case, I am doing the same. My real signal is the sin wave and hilbert transform of sin is negative cos. So, I am feeding my q data as cos wave.

Comment: That's not a phase signal. That's just the analytical signal to the audio signal.

Comment: So you know the mathematical expression for FM? It seems to your unusually focused on a component that really doesn't take you any further in this context.

Comment: @Grag first you can make a FM signal at 0Hz and then the I/Q modulator can shift the frequency up to 492.8MHz. You still need to start with an FM signal.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Now, i have modulated the signal. But, the harmonics content of a sure sin wave ( after fm demodulation ) is pretty high (about 40db). any suggestion will be highly appreciated.